# Is there a faster way to count files on macos in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We are building a program that scans through a large amount of files on the system, but before we do that we want to get a count of the amount of files on the system to be able to show a progress bar. Currently we are using a recursive function that goes through each directory and counts like this:

```
        if (Directory.Exists(path)) // if the folder is inaccesable Directory.Exists will return false
        {
            try
            {
                 currentCount += Directory.GetFiles(path).Length;
            }
            catch
            { }

            try
            {
                string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
                for (int i = 0; i < folders.Length; i++)
                {
                    currentCount = CountFiles(folders[i], currentCount);
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return (currentCount);
```

This is extremely slow. On windows, we can use the kernel32 library and use this function:

```
    private static long SizeOf(string directory)
    {
        var fcounter = new CSharpTest.Net.IO.FindFile(directory, "*", true, true, true);
        fcounter.RaiseOnAccessDenied = false;

        long size = 0, total = 0;
        fcounter.FileFound +=
            (o, e) =>
            {
                if (!e.IsDirectory)
                {
                    if (!e.IsSystem && e.Length < 5000000 && !e.IsCompressed && !e.IsEncrypted && extentions.Contains(e.Extension))
                    {
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref total);
                        size += e.Length;
                    }
                }
            };
        fcounter.Find();
        return size;
    }
```

This can scan the entire system in  around 5 seconds.

Is there a way to do something similar to this on other platforms since the kernel32 library is only available on windows?

Comment: Any other platform? Or specifically say: Linux kernal x+?

Comment: More specifically, are you looking for an algorithm and not a library, I suppose?

Comment: @AustinTFrench Currently I only care about macOS, I don't think we will run on linux.

Comment: @AustinTFrench A library with an algorithm or just an algorithm would be great. I'm not sure how the kernel32 library can work so extremely fast compared to the recursive approach.

Comment: Also I need it to be able to skip over inaccessible files or be able to handle the error and keep running, not just crash the entire function.

Comment: Why not just use `(new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles(searchPattern, new EnumerationOptions { RecurseSubdirectories = true}).Length` and leave it up to [the framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1) to pick how to do it? (Note that the `EnumerationOptions.IgnoreInaccessible` defaults to `true`)

Comment: @stuartd I tried that, but even with the IgnoreInaccessible set to true it still throws an error on inacessible folders.

Comment: That sounds like a bug with the implementation on MacOS - I ran that on my Windows c drive before posting the comment, and it skipped all the files it couldn't access and reported (eventually) 700k files. If you can write a repro for it, then I think you should file a open an issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation for FileSystemInfos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilesysteminfos?view=netcore-3.1)

This is the exact scenario for what you are trying to do from the official documentation

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class DirectoryFileCount
{

    static long files = 0;
    static long directories = 0;

    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the path to a directory:");

            string directory = Console.ReadLine();

            // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("The directory does not exist.");
            }

            // Call the GetFileSystemInfos method.
            FileSystemInfo[] infos = dir.GetFileSystemInfos();

            Console.WriteLine("Working...");

            // Pass the result to the ListDirectoriesAndFiles
            // method defined below.
            ListDirectoriesAndFiles(infos);

            // Display the results to the console. 
            Console.WriteLine("Directories: {0}", directories);
            Console.WriteLine("Files: {0}", files);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Here is where it happens.

```
    static void ListDirectoriesAndFiles(FileSystemInfo[] FSInfo)
    {
        // Check the FSInfo parameter.
        if (FSInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("FSInfo");
        }

        // Iterate through each item.
        foreach (FileSystemInfo i in FSInfo)
        {
            // Check to see if this is a DirectoryInfo object.
            if (i is DirectoryInfo)
            {
                // Add one to the directory count.
                directories++;

                // Cast the object to a DirectoryInfo object.
                DirectoryInfo dInfo = (DirectoryInfo)i;

                // Iterate through all sub-directories.
                ListDirectoriesAndFiles(dInfo.GetFileSystemInfos());
            }
            // Check to see if this is a FileInfo object.
            else if (i is FileInfo)
            {
                // Add one to the file count.
                files++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```